# Scifi, main character has munitions/arms corporation on planet with no rules. Name of book?

Tags: story-identification

The planet was run by corporations. The guy has a brother who tries to kill him so he can inherit leadership of an alliance of planets. They measured wealth in kilos (of gold). Ultimately the guy goes back in time through a wormhole and kills his dad. There is some weapon where they drop a net from outer space, which turns everything under it into gravel when it hits (special material/high terminal velocity and all). When I read it there were three parts but they had all been combined into one larger book.

Answer (score 4):

Weaponmakers series by A.E. Van Vogt?
(1943-1949)

[The Weapon Makers](http://www.google.com/search?q=%20The%20Weapon%20Makers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

[The Weapon Shops of Isher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Weapon_Shops_of_Isher)

[The Empire of Isher: The Weapon Makers / The Weapon Shops of Isher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312875002)

> Two classic Van Vogt works, The Weapon Makers and The Weapon Shops of Isher form the complete story of Robert Hedrock and the Empire of Isher. They are about revolution through time travel, the right to bear arms, the end of the universe and the beginning of the next.

It's been a *long* time since I read these, don't remember wormholes or planetary rubble-nets, but the bones of your description is in there. Orginally serialized in magazines, at least two books appeared, with reworking, possibly 3 or more.

Answer (score 1):

That's Andrew Swann's "The Hostile Takeover Trilogy."

Comment: http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/s/s-andrew-swann/